# PHP written in windows not runnable

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache2, sublimetext2

I usually use sublime text to write HTML, CSS and Java. but PHP files that I've written on my Windows machine just returns a blank page when on my linux apache2 server. Right now Im writing my php code in nano over ssh and I'd rather not keep doing that. 


I've tried to save the php file with other encodings but no result.

I dont use short tag `<?`

I save file as `filename.php`

I've used ftp and ssh to transfer the files

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Well, if one version of files work and the other does not, then there must be a difference. To find a difference between two files use the `diff` utility: `diff fileWrittenOnLinux.php fileWrittenOnMsWindows.php`  What _is_ the difference? Answering that allows you to fix the issue.

Comment: diff returned this: 1,3c1,3
< <?php
< echo "Hello World";
< ?>
\ No newline at end of file
---
> <?php
> echo "Hello World";
> ?>

Comment: A long shot, but if you have shell access on the linux box, try to run `dos2unix filename.php`

Comment: @EDP No result, I'm afraid.
I checked the error logs, 

gave me this
[Sun Feb 14 13:25:30.027471 2016] [:error] [pid 1612] [client 192.168.1.82:49494] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/html/php/win.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in Unknown on line 0

Comment: Do you mean `dos2unix filename.php` did not return any result (that's normal), or the script is still not running?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the script still wasn't running. And the error log was unrelated. But @jlemley gave me the right solution, it was a permissions issue all along. chmod fixed it for me

Comment: Sublime 3 has a setting under 'Preferences -> Settings Default', or 'Preferences -> Settings User' for default_line_ending. Make sure this is set to 'system' or 'unix'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows is not case-sensitive, Linux is. We ran into the same issue, and the cause is usually case.

If you are sure all your variables and arrays have the same case, check the error logs and see what clues they give you.

Also, double-check the file permissions and see if they are different from files that do run. FTP and SSH are likely to create files with different permissions than editing with nano.

Comment: It was a problem with the permissions. I ran chmod on the file and now it works as it should. Thank you!